# Remove spacing between pages in microsoft word for mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, microsoft

How can I remove the spaces (header/footer areas) between pages in MS word? On my PC, I just double click the spaces and it automatically removes them. When I try on my Mac, it just opens the header and footer sections.

Comment: is this possible?

Comment: Which Office do you use ? 2011 ? 2008 ?

Comment: I've been hoping for this feature to come to 2011 for ages. Disappointing that it doesn't appear to have it.

Comment: Yea documents are much easier to read through without all the unnecessary white space..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added in Word 2016 for OS-X. 
Simply hover the cursor over the break between two pages, then double click. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That feature is not supported on any version of Office for Mac to date. The closest you can get is to change the view. Look towards the bottom left of the screen. You will see icons and the 4th one should be a different color than the other 5. The 2 furthest to the left will allow you to have something that somewhat does the feature that you are looking for. One is called draft view and one is called outline view.

Or you can choose Notebook layout view. This has no gap but makes your document look like a “real notebook”

Comment: :( you are welcome anyways :)